# bootstrap gets included twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone application built with AMD modules that are loaded with requirejs. In certain modules, I need to use bootstrap functionality and hence I define the same in the dependency array in module.

When I have two modules loaded asynchronously inside the DOM and both of them have bootstrap as a dependency defined, the bootstrap functionality breaks (e.g button loading etc) because the bootstrap has now been loaded twice?

How is this situation handled?

Answer (score -1):

requireJS has a configuration do define non AMD modules, this is done throug `shim`

take a look on this [blog post](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-with-requirejs)

Comment: actually yes, i replicated your case and bootstrap.js only included once, i cannot find any problem without including any code , so i shared this link with you